# Why is Selenium only running the first test from my test suite?

Tags: selenium

I'm using Selenium stand alone server v2.3.0 on Windows XP (sp2).  I'm noticing that when I try and run my html suite against Firefox, only the first test gets executed and then the Selenium Runner just sits there without doing anything.  The command I use is

```
java -debug -jar c:/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.3.0.jar -port 4444 -userExtensions c:/selenium/user-extensions.js -htmlSuite *chrome http://www.stage.mycliusa.com c:/selenium/test/suite.html c:/selenium/report2.html
```

The HTML suite file contents are below.  Interestingly, when I run the same command switching "*chrome" with "*iehta," everything runs fine.  Any ideas why the Firefox tests are stopping after the first test? - Dave

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
  <title>mycli USA Tests - Critical Path/Live/EX</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="suiteTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="selenium"><tbody>
<tr><td><b>mycli USA Tests - Critical Path/Live/EX</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="mycliConfigNewEXJourneyAWD">mycliConfigNewEXJourneyAWD</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliContactRetailerOldEX">mycliContactRetailerOldEX</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliRAQOldEX35Base">mycliRAQOldEX35Base</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliPreApprovedEX35">mycliPreApprovedEX35</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliContactRetailerNewEX35AWD">mycliContactRetailerNewEX35AWD</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliJMLHandraiserEX">mycliJMLHandraiserEX</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliRABEBrochureEX">mycliRABEBrochureEX</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliContactRetailerNewEXJourneyAWD">mycliContactRetailerNewEXJourneyAWD</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliConfigNewEX35Base">mycliConfigNewEX35Base</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliConfigNewEX35AWD">mycliConfigNewEX35AWD</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliRABMailEX">mycliRABMailEX</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliContactRetailerNewEX35Base">mycliContactRetailerNewEX35Base</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliRABBothEX">mycliRABBothEX</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliSATDEX">mycliSATDEX</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliConfigOldEX35">mycliConfigOldEX35</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliContactRetailerNewEX35Journey">mycliContactRetailerNewEX35Journey</a></td></tr>

    <tr><td><a href="mycliConfigNewEXJourney">mycliConfigNewEXJourney</a></td></tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem turns out to be Selenium (using the -htmlSuite option) isn't able to properly process files without an ".html" extension.  When I renamed the files and ran the tests again, they sailed right through.  This bug is documented here -- http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1208.

Answer (score 0):

First function starting with "test"+fucntionName will work and so call all functions within it like

this.f1();
this.f2()

Inside that function !

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.  How do I rewrite my command or my test suite to fix the problem?